# Why is this Hash being seen as a String?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

## Problem

I am having a difficult time understanding why my Hash is being treated as a String when I call the `Hash#merge` function. When calling the following code, I receive a `NoMethodError method 'merge' for #<String:0x000...`

The line of code that is throwing the error is the following: `topic.publish({subject: 'LAB_COMPLETE', message: lab_attribs.merge(full_name: current_user.full_name)}.to_json)`. For some reason, Ruby sees the `lab_attribs` variable as a String instead of a Hash. I can't possibly see how this would be true based on the source below.

## Source

```
lab_attribs = {
    name: create_params['lab_name'],
    completed: DateTime.now,
    duration: create_params['duration'],
    final_grade: create_params['final_grade'],
    cpe: create_params['cpe'],
    user_id: create_params['user_id']
}

lab = Lab.new(lab_attribs)

if lab.save
  logger.debug("lab_attribs class: #{lab_attribs.class}, lab_attribs value: #{lab_attribs}" )
  sns = Aws::SNS::Resource.new
  topic = sns.topic(Rails.application.secrets.lab_results_topic)
  topic.publish({subject: 'LAB_COMPLETE', message: lab_attribs.merge(full_name: current_user.full_name)}.to_json)

  render json: { lab_name: lab.name }
else
  render json: { status: 422, errors: lab.errors }
end
```

## Relevant Information

`logger.debug` outputs the following:

```
lab_attribs class: Hash, lab_attribs value: {:name=>"Updating Firewall Rules", :completed=>Tue, 14 Aug 2018 11:36:01 +0000, :duration=>"1 minute", :final_grade=>"0", :cpe=>"0", :user_id=>"<snipped>"}
```

- **Ruby version**: 2.3.1
- **Rails version**: 5.1

## Logs

```
I, [2018-08-14T11:36:00.943514 #1930]  INFO -- : [d9f4566a-5b25-4e07-ace3-06f301ecf0cb] Started POST "/api/v1/labs" for 172.68.65.103 at 2018-08-14 11:36:00 +0000
I, [2018-08-14T11:36:00.946228 #1930]  INFO -- : [d9f4566a-5b25-4e07-ace3-06f301ecf0cb] Processing by Api::V1::LabsController#create as */*
I, [2018-08-14T11:36:00.946311 #1930]  INFO -- : [d9f4566a-5b25-4e07-ace3-06f301ecf0cb]   Parameters: {"lab"=>{"lab_name"=>"[FILTERED]", "task1"=>"Saved a local copy of the firewall rules", "score1"=>"0", "weight1"=>"50", "task2"=>"Blocked port 3600", "score2"=>"0", "weight2"=>"50", "final_grade"=>"0", "cpe"=>"0", "duration"=>"1 minute", "user_id"=>"<snipped>"}}
...<snipped DB calls>... 
D, [2018-08-14T11:36:01.408369 #1930] DEBUG -- : [d9f4566a-5b25-4e07-ace3-06f301ecf0cb] lab_attribs class: Hash, lab_attribs value: {:name=>"Updating Firewall Rules", :completed=>Tue, 14 Aug 2018 11:36:01 +0000, :duration=>"1 minute", :final_grade=>"0", :cpe=>"0", :user_id=>"<snipped>"}
I, [2018-08-14T11:36:01.414112 #1930]  INFO -- : [d9f4566a-5b25-4e07-ace3-06f301ecf0cb] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 468ms (ActiveRecord: 26.7ms)
F, [2018-08-14T11:36:01.414612 #1930] FATAL -- : [d9f4566a-5b25-4e07-ace3-06f301ecf0cb]   
F, [2018-08-14T11:36:01.414689 #1930] FATAL -- : [d9f4566a-5b25-4e07-ace3-06f301ecf0cb] NoMethodError (undefined method `merge' for #<String:0x0055e4df9d9558>):
F, [2018-08-14T11:36:01.414720 #1930] FATAL -- : [d9f4566a-5b25-4e07-ace3-06f301ecf0cb]   
F, [2018-08-14T11:36:01.414758 #1930] FATAL -- : [d9f4566a-5b25-4e07-ace3-06f301ecf0cb] app/controllers/api/v1/labs_controller.rb:30:in `create'
```

Comment: Is that your actual code?

Comment: Believe it or not, yes. Which is why I am perplexed

Comment: Can you provide full part from the log?

Comment: So if you pry/debug/log/puts just before that line, and see `lab_attribs.class`, `lab_attribs`, `lab_attribs.method(:merge)`, `lab_attribs.merge({ full_name: "full name" })`... what do you get?

Comment: `lab_attribs_to.to_h.merge(full_name: current_user.full_name)` try this.

Comment: What does `Lab.new` do? What does `Lab#save` do?

Comment: Ok, so I modified my code to place debug information before the merge call. It still sees the lab_attribs variable as a hash. Updating post now. I have also tried restarting the server several times.

Comment: Could you paste backtrace of your error? (Sorry for endless requests, but this is very weird.)

Comment: added some logs, there is no redacted code between the `logger.debug` and the usage of `lab_attribs.merge`

Comment: I tried adding the `to_h` method as Gabbar suggested and that did not work and still produces the same error

Comment: ok so i tried replacing the merge function with just a regular old lab_attribs[:full_name] = current_user.full_name and removed the merge code. there is definitely some code caching issues going on because it still sees the merge method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That Hash is not being seen as a String; you're misreading the error.

I'm not sure whether your backtrace is being surprisingly truncated by something, or you've just redacted the important part, but the error is not where you think it is.

The fact you're calling `merge` is unrelated to your problem, which is that [the `publish` method you are calling](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/a71396921d393d231a2614f82f108996a1a76d30/gems/aws-sdk-sns/lib/aws-sdk-sns/topic.rb#L279) calls `merge` on its argument... which you are passing as a `to_json`-built string, instead of the hash it expects.

You need to remove the `.to_json` in your call.

Comment: Yup, this was exactly the problem! I should have called the to_json method on the hash that makes up the `message` parameter of the publish function. The AWS SNS required the message to be a string and I had put the to_json in the wrong place. Unfortunately, Rails logs weren't verbose enough to make this immediately obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `to_json` on a hash converts it into a string.

```
irb(main):001:0> { foo: 'bar' }.to_json.class
=> String
```

WHile the signature is `Aws::SNS::Topic#publish(options = {}) ⇒ Types::PublishResponse`.

So you should be calling it as:

```
topic.publish(
  subject: 'LAB_COMPLETE', 
  message: lab_attribs.merge(full_name: current_user.full_name).to_json
)
```

You can clean the whole messy example up by using an Active Job and some basic hash manipulation:

```
# app/jobs/publish_job.rb
class PublishJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(**options)
    sns = Aws::SNS::Resource.new
    topic = sns.topic(Rails.application.secrets.lab_results_topic)
    topic.publish(options)
  end
end
```

---

```
# ...
def create
  lab = Lab.new(lab_attributes)
  if lab.save
    PublishJob.perform_now(
     subject: 'LAB_COMPLETE', 
     message: lab_attributes.merge(full_name: current_user.full_name).to_json
    )
    render json: { lab_name: lab.name }
  else
    render json: { status: 422, errors: lab.errors }
  end
end

private 

def lab_attributes
  create_params.slice(:duration, :final_grade, :cpe, :user_id).merge(
    completed: DateTime.now,
    name: create_params[:lab_name]
  )
end
```

Comment: This is provided that you want the message body as a JSON string.